# Cannot get ssh access to GlassFish 4.1 docker container

Tags: ssh, glassfish, docker

I've built GlassFish 4.1 docker container via Dockerfile, details here
[http://bderzhavets.blogspot.com/2015/01/dockerfile-for-glassfish-41.html](http://bderzhavets.blogspot.ru/2015/01/dockerfile-for-glassfish-41.html)

Glassfish itself work fine , however

```
*** Running /etc/my_init.d/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh...
No SSH host key available. Generating one...
Creating SSH2 RSA key; this may take some time ...
Creating SSH2 DSA key; this may take some time ...
Creating SSH2 ECDSA key; this may take some time ...
Creating SSH2 ED25519 key; this may take some time ...
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of restart.
```

Attempt to ssh

```
ssh -v root@localhost -p 49160
OpenSSH_6.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.4
. . . . . . . .
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I don't know how to fix problem , showing up in log and affecting ssh connectivity.

Comment: What does your docker run command look like? and unless you installed sshd on the container yourself it does not com installed on most docker images. You may also have to start the sshd service.

Comment: I built via phusion/baseimage  sshd is supposed to start, but it doesn't

Comment: You should accept one of the answers if it solved your problem :)

Comment: @BorisDerzhavets sshd will start only if you delete this file in the container RUN rm -f /etc/service/sshd/down

Answer (score 0):

Docker philosophy is to have one service per container. Some base images make it difficult to start services, which you have probably experienced. I would recommend to reconsider you approach and ask yourself why do you need the ssh daemon? Maybe you just want to use [docker exec](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec) ? Or maybe you would be better off by building a VM box with vagrant, stuffed with several services for you needs?

Comment: if you do insist on running ssh, you might try to use [this approach](http://devo.ps/blog/vagrant-docker-and-ansible-wtf/). Interestingly the main reason of running ssh server there was to allow provisioning with the ansible.

Comment: Thank you very much. docker exec container-id exec /usr/sbin/sshd -D  works fine for me

Comment: Great, as long as you know that you go against the flow it is fine.

Comment: you might also want to look at [this image](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker)

Answer (score 0):

Due to image phusion/baseimage doesn't provide ready to go  sshd daemon per https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker I tried workaround mentioned here https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker#login_ssh and got:-

```
[root@junolxc ~]# docker run -d -p 49160:22 -p 49161:4848  -p 49162:8080 -p 49163:8181 boris/docker-glassfish41 --enable-insecure-key
693176ea6596bf33b880dc0f58250f47fe2e35ed95f44fcd80a62eeaa3fe17a4
2015/01/08 12:26:32 Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 693176ea6596bf33b880dc0f58250f47fe2e35ed95f44fcd80a62eeaa3fe17a4: exec: "--enable-insecure-key": executable file not found in $PATH
```

I just hacked system via adding to Dockerfile  :-

```
RUN echo "/usr/sbin/sshd > log &" >> /etc/my_init.d/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh
```

---

Another option not to touch 00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh.
Create in building folder script  01_sshd_start.sh

---

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/sshd > log &

and insert in Dockerfile:-

ADD 01_sshd_start.sh /etc/my_init.d/
```

I believe would port 22 be already busy by system service "sshd" running the last hack wouldn't help me much. However, it did. I state that that system by some reasons doesn't start SSHD provided as is.

Comment: Yes, I can remove CMD("/sbin/my_init") from Dockerfile && then run docker run YOUR_IMAGE /sbin/my_init --enable-insecure-key && then include RUN /usr/sbin/enable_insecure_key in Dockerfile && get insecure ssh login to container. Just sshd daemon inside container should be up and running, otherwise all above is of no help.